# Where does this margin comes from in Bootstrap 4?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

[image: this is my html code.]

[image: this is my CSS code[![][2]]][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QZvpw.png)

I am using **Bootstrap 4** ,where does this margin comes from ??

Comment: Instead of putting an image of your code, copy paste your code in your question.

Comment: yes. provide code so that we can edit it.

Comment: can you please put the full code and , please explain your question clearly

Comment: <div class="container-fluid display-table">
    <div class="row display-table-row">
      <div class="col-md-2 display-table-cell valign-top" id="side-menu">
        <h1>Navigation</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-10 display-table-cell valign-top box">
        <div class="row">
          <header>
            <div class="col-md-5">
              <input type="text" name="" placeholder="Search..." />
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-7"></div>
          </header>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

Comment: body,html{font-family:"open sans",Helvetica,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;background-color:#F3F3F4;color:#676A6C;height:100%}#side-menu{background-color:#603E88;padding:0}#side-menu h1{color:#cdbfe3;text-align:center;margin:10px 0;font-size:25px}.box{background-color:#eee}.display-table{display:table;padding:0;height:100%}.display-table-row{display:table-row;height:100%}.display-table-cell{display:table-cell;float:none;height:100%}.valign-top{vertical-align:top}

Comment: Edit your question, don't put it in a comment.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use all the width of the page you can use `.container-fluid`

.container for a responsive fixed width container.

```
<div class="container">
  ...
</div>
```

.container-fluid for a full width container.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  ...
</div>
```

Comment: Now he uses container and not container-fluid.. So his code and the margin image are not in line with each other..

Comment: Yes I want that that's why I am using container-fluid.